# How to normalize the weights of elements in an array

Tags: linear-algebra, recreational-mathematics

I'm trying to write a function to normalize the relative weights of elements in an array.

For example:

```
Input:    [1, 1]
Output:   [0.5, 0.5]
In * Out: [0.5, 0.5] == 1

Input:    [2, 1]
Output:   [0.4, 0.2]
In * Out: [0.8, 0.2] == 1

Input:    [3, 2, 1]
Output:   [0.2142, 0.1428, 0.0714]
In * Out: [0.6426, 0.2856, 0.0714] == 1

Input:    [3, 1, 1, 1]
Output:   [0.2499, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833]
In * Out: [0.7497, 0.0833, 0.0833, 0.0833] == 1
```

The catch is: you need to be able to multiply `output` by `input` to produce a new array whose elements `sum` to `1`.

How can I achieve this?

---

p.s. apologies in advance -- I am no math whiz -- so would be great to see examples in code! I'm also terribly sorry if I've voilated the tags on this question; more than happy to change them :)

p.p.s. Examples `3` and `4` catch me out, since both `input`s have a `[0]=3` and `sum=6`... so is not as simple as it first looks (to me at least!)

Comment: As a tip, it may be helpful for you to memorize the beginnings of the decimal expansions for numbers like 1/7 and 1/12. That would help you to guess what is going on in those examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the sum of the squares of the inputs, then output should be the input but with each entry divided by $N $. This works because the sum of the products will be a sum of things like $a*(a/N)=\dfrac{a^2}{N}$ so you'll have (sum of squares)$/N$, which is $1$ by choice of $N $.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I knew I had come to the right place! I would accept it sooner, but I need to wait another 2 minutes, apparently...